# HTTP Range request multipart/byteranges - is there a CRLF at the end?

Tags: http, http-range

[RFC7233](http://httpwg.github.io/specs/rfc7233.html#status.206) is nice and clear, except for line endings.

I am specifically interested the HTTP response body of a `multipart/byteranges` response. I assume each line is terminated by a CRLF as HTTP headers are, but this document isn't explicit about it. What I'm totally befuddled about is the last line: `--THIS_SEPARATOR_SEPARATES--`. Is it followed by a CRLF?

Full block:

```
HTTP/1.1 206 Partial Content
Date: Wed, 15 Nov 1995 06:25:24 GMT
Last-Modified: Wed, 15 Nov 1995 04:58:08 GMT
Content-Length: 1741
Content-Type: multipart/byteranges; boundary=THIS_STRING_SEPARATES

--THIS_STRING_SEPARATES
Content-Type: application/pdf
Content-Range: bytes 500-999/8000

...the first range...
--THIS_STRING_SEPARATES
Content-Type: application/pdf
Content-Range: bytes 7000-7999/8000

...the second range
--THIS_STRING_SEPARATES--
```

Sorry I really can't find it, so help would be greatly appreciated.
NOTE: please no gut feelings, only RFC references.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you read RFC 7233 more carefully, [Appendix A](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7233#appendix-A) refers to [RFC 2046 Section 5.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2046#section-5.1) for the actual format of the MIME data within the HTTP body:

> When a 206 (Partial Content) response message includes the content of
> multiple ranges, they are transmitted as body parts in a multipart
> message body ([RFC2046], Section 5.1) with the media type of
> "multipart/byteranges".

RFC 2046 Section 5.1 defines the formal definition of the "multipart" media type and how its boundaries are formatted and parsed.

To answer your question, here is the formal syntax from RFC 2046:

```
   The boundary delimiter MUST occur at the beginning of a line, i.e.,
   following a CRLF, and the initial CRLF is considered to be attached
   to the boundary delimiter line rather than part of the preceding
   part.  The boundary may be followed by zero or more characters of
   linear whitespace. It is then terminated by either another CRLF and
   the header fields for the next part, or by two CRLFs, in which case
   there are no header fields for the next part.  If no Content-Type
   field is present it is assumed to be "message/rfc822" in a
   "multipart/digest" and "text/plain" otherwise.

   NOTE:  The CRLF preceding the boundary delimiter line is conceptually
   attached to the boundary so that it is possible to have a part that
   does not end with a CRLF (line  break).  Body parts that must be
   considered to end with line breaks, therefore, must have two CRLFs
   preceding the boundary delimiter line, the first of which is part of
   the preceding body part, and the second of which is part of the
   encapsulation boundary.
```

...

```
   The boundary delimiter line following the last body part is a
   distinguished delimiter that indicates that no further body parts
   will follow.  Such a delimiter line is identical to the previous
   delimiter lines, with the addition of two more hyphens after the
   boundary parameter value.

     --gc0pJq0M:08jU534c0p--

   NOTE TO IMPLEMENTORS:  Boundary string comparisons must compare the
   boundary value with the beginning of each candidate line.  An exact
   match of the entire candidate line is not required; it is sufficient
   that the boundary appear in its entirety following the CRLF.
```

...

```
   The only mandatory global parameter for the "multipart" media type is
   the boundary parameter, which consists of 1 to 70 characters from a
   set of characters known to be very robust through mail gateways, and
   NOT ending with white space. (If a boundary delimiter line appears to
   end with white space, the white space must be presumed to have been
   added by a gateway, and must be deleted.)  It is formally specified
   by the following BNF:

     boundary := 0*69 bcharsnospace

     bchars := bcharsnospace / " "

     bcharsnospace := DIGIT / ALPHA / "'" / "(" / ")" /
                      "+" / "_" / "," / "-" / "." /
                      "/" / ":" / "=" / "?"

   Overall, the body of a "multipart" entity may be specified as
   follows:

     dash-boundary := "--" boundary
                      ; boundary taken from the value of
                      ; boundary parameter of the
                      ; Content-Type field.

     multipart-body := [preamble CRLF]
                       dash-boundary transport-padding CRLF
                       body-part *encapsulation
                       close-delimiter transport-padding
                       [CRLF epilogue]

     transport-padding := *LWSP-char
                          ; Composers MUST NOT generate
                          ; non-zero length transport
                          ; padding, but receivers MUST
                          ; be able to handle padding
                          ; added by message transports.

     encapsulation := delimiter transport-padding
                      CRLF body-part

     delimiter := CRLF dash-boundary

     close-delimiter := delimiter "--"

     preamble := discard-text

     epilogue := discard-text

     discard-text := *(*text CRLF) *text
                     ; May be ignored or discarded.

     body-part := MIME-part-headers [CRLF *OCTET]
                  ; Lines in a body-part must not start
                  ; with the specified dash-boundary and
                  ; the delimiter must not appear anywhere
                  ; in the body part.  Note that the
                  ; semantics of a body-part differ from
                  ; the semantics of a message, as
                  ; described in the text.

     OCTET := <any 0-255 octet value>
```

Each delimiter at the beginning of a new part is terminated by a CRLF, and any CRLF that immediately precedes a delimiter is parsed as part of the boundary and not the data of the preceding part.  However, there is no CRLF on the end of the final closing boundary, unless there is an epilogue present (which is very rarely used in email, and I have never seen it used in HTTP as there is no way to determine when then epilogue ends unless there is a valid `Content-Length` header present, which is not supposed to be used with self-terminating content types like MIME).

Comment: Eff missed the Appendix. Wow, thanks for the super prompt and concise response!

Comment: if only everyone was half as thorough as you seem to be :)

Answer (score 0):

That spec references:

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2046#section-5.1.1

Which explicitly states:

> ```
>  --gc0pJq0M:08jU534c0p
> ```
>
> The boundary delimiter MUST occur at the beginning of a line, i.e.,
> following a CRLF, and the initial CRLF is considered to be attached
> to the boundary delimiter line rather than part of the preceding
> part.  The boundary may be followed by zero or more characters of
> linear whitespace. It is then terminated by either another CRLF and
> the header fields for the next part, or by two CRLFs, in which case
> there are no header fields for the next part.  If no Content-Type
> field is present it is assumed to be "message/rfc822" in a
> "multipart/digest" and "text/plain" otherwise.

Comment: What you quote refers to the first and subsequent boundaries in between MIME parts, but does not cover the final closing boundary, which is NOT terminated by a CRLF (unless an epilogue is present).

Comment: Thanks for pointing out rfc2046 and the amazingly fast response Evert. Because Remy also answered the ending CRLF part I had to accept his response. Appreciate your time.

Comment: No problem =) Glad you got your answer